# Universe Dictionary ITem multipart key, second part is multi-valued

Tags: universe

Trying to use

```
TRANS(SPEC.ORDR,@ID:"*":@RECORD<27,@CNT>,27,'X')
```

Universe is returning an error message on @CNT, assuming not used in our Universe flavour, anyone know what the actual trans code would be?

Comment: I too would be interested to see if anyone has anything for this. I have never head of (AT)CNT, but I have tried (AT)NV, (AT)NI, (AT)NS and never gotten it to work right from an I descriptor. I usually just use SUBR for things like that currently.

Comment: Think I might be thinking of an SB+ common variable, though that would have to convert to an ITYPE logically ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the CATS is base so this should work for you. A similarly built I-Descriptor on my system certainly does the concatenation correctly, but I don't have an easy to find example to test the TRANS on top. It does bring back the expected number of blanks based the on the 'X'.

```
TRANS(SPEC.ORDR,SUBR('-CATS',REUSE(@ID:'*'),@RECORD<27>),27,'X')
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer, worked perfects. Is this documented anywhere in the manuals? Can't find a reference to it.

Comment: There are references to CATS (including reference to -CATS), TRANS and REUSE in the BASIC Command Reference guide, but nothing telling you how to do that specifically, so far as I know.  This sort of this always used to be done in the shell with I-Descriptors (or F-Correlatives if you are really old school) so I am not sure it would cross anyone's mind to document these sorts of things specifically.